# How can I insert an image in a QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qtextedit

So I'm trying to insert an image on a Qtexteditor, so far I only managed to turn the Qtexteditor all white, i tried this:

```
ACTIVATED_CSS = 'QTextEdit {image: url(einstein.jpg);}'
```

So I'm receiving some numbers from 1 to 7 (via TCP) in random order, and when the code receives them a corresponding Qtexteditor  'lights' up with a green bakground, but now I want to change to an image when lights up.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import threading
import asyncio
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from TcpClient import TcpClient
from play_wav_files import PlaySoundThread


NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS = 'QTextEdit {background-color: black; font: 30px; color: white;}'
ACTIVATED_CSS = 'QTextEdit {color: red; font: 25px; background-color: green;  font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;}'
NORMAL_CSS = 'QTextEdit {color: white; font: 25px; background-color: grey;  font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;}'
ACTIVATED_CSS_AR = 'QTextEdit {color: red; font: 25px; background-color: green;  font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px; margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px;}'
NORMAL_CSS_AR = 'QTextEdit {color: white; font: 25px; background-color: grey;  font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px; margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px;}'
TCP_CLIENT = TcpClient()
EW_CONSTANT = TCP_CLIENT.nepoch * TCP_CLIENT.nwords
ASYNC_LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()

#TENTAR COM IMAGENS CARAS ------------------

#ACTIVATED_CSS = 'QTextEdit {image: url(einstein.jpg);}'
#ACTIVATED_CSS_AR = 'QTextEdit {image: url(einstein.jpg);}'

class QtSideGui(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        # buttons:
        self.conn_button = QPushButton('Recieve server instructions')
        self.clear_button = QPushButton('Clear status')
        self.insert_code_1 = QPushButton('Insert Code 1')
        self.insert_code_update_1 = QPushButton('insert update code 1')
        self.insert_code_2 = QPushButton('Insert Code 2')
        self.insert_code_update_2 = QPushButton('insert update code 2')
        self.insert_code_3 = QPushButton('Insert Code 3')
        self.insert_code_update_3 = QPushButton('insert update code 3')
        self.insert_code_4 = QPushButton('Insert Code 4')
        self.insert_code_update_4 = QPushButton('insert update code 4')
        self.insert_code_5 = QPushButton('Insert Code 5')
        self.insert_code_update_5 = QPushButton('insert update code 5')
        self.insert_code_6 = QPushButton('Insert Code 6')
        self.insert_code_update_6 = QPushButton('insert update code 6')
        self.insert_code_7 = QPushButton('Insert Code 7')
        self.insert_code_update_7 = QPushButton('insert update code 7')
        self.insert_code_1.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_1.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_2.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_2.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_3.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_3.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_4.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_4.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_5.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_5.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_6.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_6.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_7.setHidden(True)
        self.insert_code_update_7.setHidden(True)
        self.clear_button.setHidden(True)

        # Text Boxes:
        self._l_blank1 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank1.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._l_blank2 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank2.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._l_blank3 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank3.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._l_blank4 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank4.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._l_blank5 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank5.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._l_blank6 = QTextEdit('')
        self._l_blank6.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)
        self._updadeQText = QTextEdit('-')
        self._updadeQText.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_HIDDEN_CSS)

        self._l_sim = QTextEdit()
        self._l_sim.setText('                             SIM')
        self._l_sim.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_sim.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

        self._l_nao = QTextEdit()
        self._l_nao.setText('                             NÃO')
        self._l_nao.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_nao.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

        self._l_fome = QTextEdit()
        self._l_fome.setText('                             FOME')
        self._l_fome.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_fome.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

        self._l_sede = QTextEdit()  
        self._l_sede.setText('                             SEDE')
        self._l_sede.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_sede.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

        self._l_urinar = QTextEdit() 
        self._l_urinar.setText('                             URINAR')
        self._l_urinar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_urinar.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

        self._l_ar = QTextEdit()
        self._l_ar.setText('                            AR')
        self._l_ar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_ar.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS_AR)

        self._l_posicao = QTextEdit()
        self._l_posicao.setText('                             POSIÇÃO')
        self._l_posicao.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._l_posicao.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)


        # Layout:
        self._layoutGL = QGridLayout()
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_sim, 3, 1)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_nao, 3, 4)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_fome, 4, 2)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_sede, 4, 3)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_urinar, 2, 1)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_posicao, 2, 4)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank1, 2, 2)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank2, 2, 3)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank3, 3, 3)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank4, 3, 2)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank5, 4, 1)
        self._layoutGL.addWidget(self._l_blank6, 4, 4)

        self._layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        self._layoutH.addWidget(self._l_blank2,35.5)
        self._layoutH.addWidget(self._l_ar,29)
        self._layoutH.addWidget(self._l_blank3,35.5)
        self._layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        self._layoutV.addWidget(self._updadeQText)
        self._layoutV.addLayout(self._layoutH)
        self._layoutV.addLayout(self._layoutGL)
        self._layoutV.addWidget(self.conn_button)
        self._layoutV.addWidget(self.clear_button)

        # instruct QDialog to display:
        self.setWindowTitle("Code receiver")
        self.setLayout(self._layoutV)
        self.setFocus()

        # QT signal and slots connections
        self.conn_button.clicked.connect(self.open_tcp_connection)
        self.clear_button.clicked.connect(self.set_all_down)
        self.insert_code_1.clicked.connect(self.set_sim_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_1.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_sim)
        self.insert_code_2.clicked.connect(self.set_nao_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_2.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_nao)
        self.insert_code_3.clicked.connect(self.set_fome_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_3.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_fome)
        self.insert_code_4.clicked.connect(self.set_sede_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_4.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_sede)
        self.insert_code_5.clicked.connect(self.set_urinar_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_5.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_urinar)
        self.insert_code_6.clicked.connect(self.set_ar_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_6.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_ar)
        self.insert_code_7.clicked.connect(self.set_posicao_highlight)
        self.insert_code_update_7.clicked.connect(self.set_update_text_posicao)

    # Useful methods:
    @staticmethod
    def pick_up_text_and_update(text, text_code):
        return text + '  ' + text_code

    def open_tcp_connection(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._asyncio_thread, args=(ASYNC_LOOP,)).start()

    def set_update_text_sim(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'SIM'))

    def set_sim_highlight(self):
        self._l_sim.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_update_text_nao(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'NÃO'))

    def set_nao_highlight(self):
        self._l_nao.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_update_text_fome(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'FOME'))

    def set_fome_highlight(self):
        self._l_fome.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_update_text_sede(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'SEDE'))

    def set_sede_highlight(self):
        self._l_sede.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_update_text_urinar(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'URINAR'))

    def set_urinar_highlight(self):
        self._l_urinar.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_update_text_ar(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'AR'))

    def set_ar_highlight(self):
        self._l_ar.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS_AR)

    def set_update_text_posicao(self):
        self._updadeQText.setText(self.pick_up_text_and_update(self._updadeQText.toPlainText(), 'POSIÇÃO'))

    def set_posicao_highlight(self):
        self._l_posicao.setStyleSheet(ACTIVATED_CSS)

    def set_all_down(self):
        self._l_sim.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)
        self._l_nao.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)
        self._l_fome.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)
        self._l_sede.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)
        self._l_urinar.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)
        self._l_ar.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS_AR)
        self._l_posicao.setStyleSheet(NORMAL_CSS)

    def download_code(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._asyncio_thread, args=(ASYNC_LOOP,)).start()

    async def get_one_code(self, tcp_client):
        serv_code = tcp_client.read_only_one_code_from_server()
        self.clear_button.click()
        t_sound = PlaySoundThread(thread_id=serv_code,
                                  name=serv_code,
                                  counter=int(serv_code),
                                  index_vec=int(serv_code))
        t_sound.start()
        self.decode_code(serv_code)
        if tcp_client.count - 1 in [0, EW_CONSTANT + 1, EW_CONSTANT * 2 + 2,
                                EW_CONSTANT * 3 + 3, EW_CONSTANT * 4 + 4,
                                EW_CONSTANT * 5 + 5, EW_CONSTANT * 6 + 6]:
            self.update_code_in_label(serv_code)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            self.clear_button.click()
        elif tcp_client.count - 1 in [EW_CONSTANT * 7 + 7,
                                EW_CONSTANT * 8 + 8, EW_CONSTANT * 9 + 9,
                                EW_CONSTANT * 10 + 10, EW_CONSTANT * 11 + 11,
                                EW_CONSTANT * 12 + 12, EW_CONSTANT * 13 + 13]:
            self.update_code_in_label(serv_code)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            self.clear_button.click()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        t_sound.join()
        return serv_code

    def check_aviability_func(self):
        print('aviability')

    def _asyncio_thread(self, async_loop):
        async_loop.run_until_complete(self.open_tcp_connections_and_enqueue())

    async def open_tcp_connections_and_enqueue(self):
        print("opening connection...")
        TCP_CLIENT.init_connection_with_server()
        print("connection ok!")
        tasks = [self.get_one_code(tcp_client=TCP_CLIENT) for num in range(999)]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        results = [task.result() for task in completed]

    def decode_code(self, code):
        if code == 1:
            self.insert_code_1.click()
        elif code == 2:
            self.insert_code_2.click()
        elif code == 3:
            self.insert_code_3.click()
        elif code == 4:
            self.insert_code_4.click()
        elif code == 5:
            self.insert_code_5.click()
        elif code == 6:
            self.insert_code_6.click()
        elif code == 7:
            self.insert_code_7.click()
        else:
            print('unknown code received')
            self.set_all_down()
            print("error")
            exit(1)

    def update_code_in_label(self, code):
        self.clear_button.click()
        print('code inside update: {}'.format(code))
        if code == 1:
            self.insert_code_update_1.click()
        elif code == 2:
            self.insert_code_update_2.click()
        elif code == 3:
            self.insert_code_update_3.click()
        elif code == 4:
            self.insert_code_update_4.click()
        elif code == 5:
            self.insert_code_update_5.click()
        elif code == 6:
            self.insert_code_update_6.click()
        elif code == 7:
            self.insert_code_update_7.click()
        #time.sleep(1)
        self.clear_button.click()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox.question(self,
                                               "QUIT",
                                               "Are you sure want to stop process?",
                                               QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
            exit(-1)
        else:
            event.ignore



try:
    ap = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ap.setStyle('Fusion')
    ap.setStyleSheet('QApplication {background-color: black;}')
    dialog = QtSideGui()
    dialog.setStyleSheet('QtSideGui {background-color: black;}')
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(ap.exec_())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    QMessageBox.information(ap, 'Information', 'An error has occurred.')
```

Do you haveany idea on how I can do this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the image using Qt Style Sheet then you should use `background-image: url(/path/of/image);`, and it is advisable to use the full path. If you want to change the image it is necessary to force it and for that you must use the `unpolish()` and `polish()` methods, in that order.

On the other hand if you want to change the Qt Style Sheet depending on the status of the widget then use a q-property.

I will not use the code you provide for obvious reasons, so in the following example I generate random numbers making a single QTextEdit active. On the other hand, the structure of the project is as follows:

```
├── images
│   ├── image1.png
│   └── image2.png
└── main.py
```

```py
import os
import random
import itertools
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def isActive(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_activated"):
            self._activated = False
        return self._activated

    def setActive(self, v):
        if self.isActive() == v:
            return
        self._activated = v
        self.style().unpolish(self)
        self.style().polish(self)

    active = QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, fget=isActive, fset=setActive)


current_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
image_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, "images"))

QSS = """
TextEdit[active="false"]{
    background-image: url(%s);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
TextEdit[active="true"]{
    background-image: url(%s);  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
""" % (
    os.path.join(image_dir, "image1.png").replace(os.path.sep, '/'),
    os.path.join(image_dir, "image2.png").replace(os.path.sep, '/'),
)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.m_textedits = []

        for r, c in itertools.product((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2)):
            te = TextEdit()
            lay.addWidget(te, r, c)
            self.m_textedits.append(te)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.generate, interval=500)
        timer.start()

    def generate(self):
        i = random.randint(0, len(self.m_textedits) - 1)
        for j, te in enumerate(self.m_textedits):
            te.setActive(i == j)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried your code, but all the TextEdit show plain white @eyllanesc

Comment: @FranciscaMachado have you placed the images "image1.png" and "image2.png" in the "images" folder on the side of your .py file? If so, what is the value of `image_dir`?

Comment: yes I did, the images_dir is : 'C:\\Users\\meca\\Desktop\\images' @eyllanesc

Comment: try with my update, Qt uses the unix separator "/" but python uses "\\" generating an incompatibility.