# Is there any way I can add pictures to my QTextEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a word processor like Microsoft word but I don't know how to add pictures to QTextEdit

```
self.textwidget = QtWidgets.QTextWidget(sellf.centralwidget)
self.textwidget.add_pixpap(QPixmap("filename"))
```

help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe this Site helps_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771875/how-can-i-insert-an-image-in-a-qtextedit
or this 
https://learndataanalysis.org/insert-an-image-in-a-text-editor-qtextedit-in-pyqt5/

Comment: There is no class named QTextWidget in Qt